# Warhammer story that covers someone's transition from human to ghoul

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

In the Warhammer fantasy universe, a [ghoul](http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoul) usually starts life as a human, and turns into a ghoul through cannibalising other humans or eating their remains.

[image]

Does anyone know of anything published by the [Black Library](http://www.blacklibrary.com/) (short story or perhaps even a passage in a novel), that covers a ghoul's transition from human to ghoul? I've searched their site many times and have not been able to find it, I've even emailed them but in the reply was told:

> There *could be such a story*, we apologize but no one here can be certain.

So I'm wondering has anyone here come across it?

Comment: Can you remember anything else?

Comment: There's nothing to remember, I've never read it.  I want to know if it exists.

Comment: Oh, this is going to be hard.

Comment: So no one even told you anything about this? You're just hoping that in the  mess of novels published by the Black Library, something like this exists?

Comment: @user14111 - Um, this is not my question. It's just the question for which I spent two hours searching 80 percent of all Warhammer Fantasy novels.

Comment: I even wrote a script to make it easier.

Comment: There is one small chapter in the old undead army book (before the split between khemri and vampire counts) where it is told that over generations of eating teh dead the inhabitants of a village became something else (ghouls).  But no actual story there only the description.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### There probably isn't one

There are several hundred published Warhammer Fantasy books from the Black Library. Of the 153 that I was able to search, 64 contain the word (or strictly speaking, string) "ghoul".

"No actual ghouls" means that the string *ghoul* appears, but ghouls themselves aren't mentioned. This basically means words such as *ghoulish*.

**The Hour of Shadows**: No actual ghouls

**The Claws of Chaos**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Age of Legend**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Ancient Blood**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation. This one has humans closely associated with ghouls, though, and one such character makes medicine that secretly contains human organs, strongly suggesting that she is turning her people into the ghouls with which they associate.

**Archaon: Everchosen** : No actual ghouls

**Archaon: Lord of Chaos**: No actual ghouls

**Blighted Empire**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Blood for the Blood God**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Bloodborn**: Lots of ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Bloodforged**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen.

**Bloodsworn**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation.

**Charnel Congress**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Curse of the Necrarch**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Dead Winter**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Deathblade: A Tale of Malus Darkblade**: No actual ghouls

**Dominion**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Empire**: No actual ghouls

**Ghoul King: Conqueror of Worms**: Ghouls presumably seen, but according to the questioner, there are no ghoul transformations.

**Ghoul King: Empire of Maggots**: Same

**Gilead's Blood**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**God King**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Gotrek & Felix: Kinslayer**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Gotrek and Felix: City of the Damned**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Gotrek and Felix: Road of Skulls**: Ghouls  mentioned, but not seen

**Gotrek and Felix: The Anthology**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Grey Seer**: No actual ghouls

**Grimblades**: No actual ghouls

**Hammers of Ulric**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Harbinger**: No actual ghouls

**Headtaker**: No actual ghouls

**Inheritance**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Knight of the Blazing Sun**: No actual ghouls

**Marienburg's Stand**: No actual ghouls

**Master of Death**: Ghouls mentioned, in particular the process of creating them. No transformation

**Master of Dragons**: No actual ghouls

**Master of Mourkain**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Nagash the Sorcerer**: No actual ghouls

**Nagash the Unbroken**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Neferata**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation.

**Picking the Bones**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Plague Priest**: No actual ghouls

**Retribution**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Sigmar's Blood**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Skarsnik**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Sword of Vengeance**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation.

**Temple of the Serpent**: No actual ghouls

**Thanquol's Doom**: No actual ghouls

**The Blades of Chaos**: No actual ghouls

**The Curse of Khaine** : Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**The End Times: The Bone Cage**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**The End Times: The Fall of Altdorf**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**The End Times: The Lord of the End Times**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**The End Times:The Return of Nagash**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**The End Times: The Rise of the Horned Rat**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**The Fangs of the Asp**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**The Great Maw**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**The Last Man**: No actual ghouls

**The Red Duke**: Ghouls seen, but no tranformation

**The Serpent Queen**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

**Vampireslayer**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation. However, a ghoul is mentioned to possibly be someone known to the townspeople, indicating the transformation can be rapid.

**Vermintide**: Ghouls mentioned, but not seen

**Warrior Priest**: No actual ghouls

**Wolf of Sigmar (Time of Legends)**: No actual ghouls

**Zombieslayer**: Ghouls seen, but no transformation

The preceding list comes from [these series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Warhammer_Fantasy_novels), as well as several standalones:

- **Chaos**
- **Dwarves**
- **Elves**
- **Empire**
- **Gilead**
- **Gotrek and Felix**
- **Time of Legends**
- **Vampires**
- **Warhammer Heroes**
- **Skaven**
- **Storm of Magic**
- **The End Times**

---

I also checked all the listed Warhammer short stories that I could:

None of those whose description I could find has ghouls as a main subject, and as such are fairly unlikely to depict the process of a ghoul transformation, or discuss the details thereof.

---

Finally, of course, I searched online extensively for Warhammer novels containing ghoul transformations, and found none.

Comment: While this answer makes me sad, the effort put in is very impressive! Very well done!